# can I copy-paste SQL Server 2005 Express on XP Pro or Vista machine and make it work without installer?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, windows, installation

I am having installer problems on several machines trying to install SQL Server Express 2005 Express as well as later versions (but I would be happy with 2005 anyway). However, I do have one machine where it runs fine. So, is there a way to clone the installation by copy-pasting the files and then doing some magic to make it work? So far when I put the folder into another XP Pro machine and tried launch ssmsee.exe, it didn't start - command executed in cmd quietly and nothing happened.

Is this approach in fact doable with some relevant fixes? Or is the installer the only way?

Comment: I would imagine the installer sets registry settings, which you wouldn't get if you copied and pasted the binary files and libraries and executables. There's probably a way to copy registry settings to, but I'm not certain about that.

Comment: Might this be a better question for the serverfault site? You can script SQL Server installation, but it doesn't sound like that's what you're looking for, reg cloning and such.

Comment: No, you cannot copy an existing installation. Installer is the only way.

Answer (score 1):

No, you need to go through the installer to get SQL Express working on the other machines.